# unicode literal to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, unicode-literals

Simple and newbie question,

```
>>> print ( u'Hello\u0020World !')
Hello World !
>>> s = "Hello\u0020World !"
>>> print (u's)

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Why??

Comment: `print (u's)` where is the other `'`? Anyway.. `s = u'Hello\u0020World !'; print(s)` (and if this is not desired, please explain what *is* desired because it is not clear). Note how the literal is just a value which can be assigned.

Comment: @user2864740 You should be able to do, `print(s.decode('unicode-escape'))` => `u'Hello World !'`

Comment: well, the s is a variable, not a string)

Comment: print(s.decode('unicode-escape'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: `u'Hello\u0020World !' == "Hello\u0020World !"` is `True` because the `u` prefix on string literals is a **no-op** in Python 3. It is only there to support compatibility with code that runs on both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: The prefix is *just a literal notation* to create a value. Once you have a value, literal notations no longer apply to that value, as you already produced it. Nor is it needed at all here.

Comment: it's very simple: i get a string like this "\u05dc\u05d0 \u05de\u05d1" to a variable, and i need to "unicode" it, and then to append the decoded text to a file.

Comment: OK. I'm not sure this is the elegant way, but it works for me: s = "Hello\u0020World !".encode("utf-8")
print (s.decode())

Comment: @user1641071: That is completely unnecessary. Just pass `s` as-is to `print()`, no need to encode and decode it.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment is fine.  The problem is with your `print` call -- you do not need (and cannot) specify the type of the variable; adding a `u` is nonsensical, and having a single quote is a syntax error.  All you need to do is `print()` your variable:

```
s = "Hello\u0020World !"
print(s)
```

Your comment of

```
 s = "Hello\u0020World !".encode("utf-8")
 print(s.decode())
```

is doing exactly the same thing, just with more work.